# Hover over commentors yields reputation title, but hover over asker / answerers and get nothing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tooltips

[image]

Should we not also see rep when you hover over the OP's username / profile link?

I know the reputation is right below it, but not everyone will expect to look in in a different place.

Comment: I would be surprised if most users even know that a comment poster's rep show up when you hover over his/her username... (I sure didn't before reading this question.)

Comment: @adamjford I didn't even think about that when I read the question -- I always click through to their profile, I don't think I ever noticed the hover text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would look ridiculous to have hover text of `597 rep` right over regular text of `597 rep`.

"Not all people are smart like that"? You can't help them no matter what you do.

Hovering over the avatar image for 1k+ users shows the user card, which displays the reputation score. If you really want the reputation in a hover format, there you go.

Comment: Agreed. There's already some much stuff that pops up when you hover over pretty much anything. That undecorated, does-not-pop-up-even-more-stuff link is my favorite mouse resting spot. (-:

Comment: @Mat I only count 5 popups and 15 tool tips for one question, answer and comment. I don't see that as excessive ;)